# using NG-CLASS inside of a mat table referring to a "row" element for css decleration

Tags: css, angular

I have a mat table with several columns. One of the columns is a status field. I want to put colored badges in that column for the status that record has. I made them non clickable buttons. A record can have one of the 3 statuses "Completed", "Deleted", and "Canceled". I cannot seem to get it to work dynamically when it loads to set the colors. I have seen many examples where people use ng-class and I am trying hard to implement it, or more so to refer to the value of row.OrderStatus.

HTML

```
<!-- Status Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  <button ng-class="row.OrderStatus">{{row.OrderStatus}}</button>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

CSS

```
.Completed{
  background: green;
}

.Cancelled{
  background: yellow;
}

.Deleted{
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the incorrect syntax for `ngClass`. Check out the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) for the correct syntax.

This should work for you.

```html
<button [ngClass]="{'Completed': row.OrderStatus === 'Completed', 'Deleted': row.OrderStatus === 'Deleted', 'Cancelled': row.OrderStatus === 'Cancelled'}">
    {{row.OrderStatus}}
</button>
```

Comment: Worked perfect Nash! guess the example I had found was old.

Comment: @Casey Anytime  You were using the AngularJS syntax so I guess you found an AngularJS example instead.